# How to call NTDLL.DLL function from kernel mode (x64, WIN7)

Tags: windows-7, kernel, call, 64-bit

I need to call ntdll.dll function (for example ZwCreateThread, isn't exported by the kernel) from kernel mode process. But ntdll.dll it is user mode module. How i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

In general that is impossible. DLLs cannot be used in kernel mode.

You have to search for the kernel-mode equivalent of the function. For ZwCreateThread it is PsCreateSystemThread.

Comment: Most NTDLL functions has a corresponding kernel-mode function with the same name in NTOSKRNL. Be aware of the difference between Nt* vs Zw* (most of the time you want to use Zw*).