# Loading DLL in windows kernel mode driver's address space

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver

How to load a dll into a kernel mode driver's address space ?
In user mode we have LoadLibraryA( ) to load a dll. I'm looking for kernel mode windows API to load the dll in driver's address space.

I'm trying to do the following,
Below is the user space code

```
HMODULE hNtdll = LoadLibraryA("ntdll.dll");
if (hNtdll) {
    NtAlpcCreatePort          = (PNtAlpcCreatePort)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "NtAlpcCreatePort");
}
```

Please suggest kernel mode equivalent of above piece of code.

For GetProcAddress i was able to find the kernel mode equivalent MmGetSystemRoutineAddress( ). But i couldn't find the LoadLibraryA( ) equivalent in kernel mode.

Comment: what would you do if you could load ntdll.dll into kernel space? Do you think any of the functions in ntdll.dll are designed to work in kernel space or will they just crash if you call them because they're not meant for that?

Answer (score 3):

You can't load user-land libraries to kernel-land. They simply wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks @rgnt. I got your point. Now i have a follow up query - are DLLs meant only for user mode ? Can we load any dll in kernel mode ? Are DLLs even meant for kernel mode ? On internet i see people saying DLLs can't be used in kernel mode. Please confirm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137681/how-to-call-ntdll-dll-function-from-kernel-mode-x64-win7

Comment: @ShaktiSingh, DLLs are only available in userland. You can only statically link aganist other libraries in kernelland.